# Appeal on Schengen visa

Tags: schengen, visa-refusals

The first time I applied for Schengen visa I was refused. And now, I'm confused whether I will appeal or re-apply.

The following are the documents I submitted:

1. Invitation letter from my cousin stating that he will take charge all my expenses
2. Birth certificate as proof of relationship but not all were authenticated from National Statistics Office
3. Bank Certificate with only enough money for my round trip ticket
4. Passport with stamp from my Singapore  travel last year
5. Certificate of my employment stating my salary, position, length of service, compensation and benefits
6. Company ID and 3 months payslip

I was refused due to "Your intention to leave the territory of the member state before the expiry of the visa could not be ascertained."

Comment: Which country are you from and how much do you earn? Provide information on your salary, position, length of service, compensation and benefits.

Comment: @Sheik Paul Im from Phippines, basic salary is 15 thousand, 17mos bonuses. Ive been with my company for 5 years. We also have medical allowance including our dependents up 150k.

Comment: I wanted to know the specific reason why it was refused.

Comment: @user59540 Schengen refusals do not get specific about the reason, the specific grounds must be inferred.

Comment: @Gayot Fow They return the pictures I sent to them that I'm with my cousin and with his family. And also as a proof of our relationship. But does this means that they are not convinced of our relationship as cousin?

Comment: I upvoted; get a few more and then you will be able to chat

Comment: @Gayot Fow What do mean upvoted?

Comment: @user59540 The refusal was not because they doubted your relationship with him. They have doubts about your likelihood of returning to Philippines . Looking at your income, economics is a factor. It's always a challenge getting a visa from an economically disadvantaged country to visit an advanced country. Do you have other travel history outside Philippines to developed countries?

Comment: @user59540 they returned the pictures because it is their procedures to return that sort of thing.

Comment: @Sheik Paul No, I traveled once in Singapore. What could be an additional document I can add? I want to appeal. Do I have to present a letter of approved leave?

Comment: @user59540 A letter of approved leave is a [requirement](http://www.consulfrance-washington.org/IMG/pdf/shengen310.pdf) for Schengen visa per the French Embassy in Washington DC. For your appeal, review the list of required documents and make sure all are included PLUS any other documents you believe will make your case stronger.